# Как можно перенести описание товара между базами данных 1С?

Tags: 1с

как можно перенести описание товаров с одного базы на другую версии и конфигурации одинаковые у баз данных "1С предприятие 8.3" и "Розница 2.3".
Одни и те же товары присутствуют в бд надо только описание перенести.
Сервер локальный

Comment: Одна из баз полная копия другой? Или просто одинаковые конфигурации и товары вручную заносились в разных базах?